# Why do weights act binary in Blender (no matter the weight I give they act as they are = 1.0)?

Tags: rigging, bones

I am trying to weight paint a mesh and I have been stuck for a few hours now. I am trying to weight paint this wire which would need gradually decreasing weights for it to move naturally, but for some reason when I paint any weight on it (even 0.001) it acts as if I painted 1.0 on it, no transition at all. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

I have 2 bones and have already posed on of them to move the red parts in the mesh that is why it is not in position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a vertex is part of only one vertex group, whether it has a weight of 1 or 0.01, it makes no differnce: the influence of the bone on it will be 100%.

But if a vertex is part of 2 vertex groups, the weight will be taken into account, for example a vertex that is part of vertex group A with a weight of 1 and part of the vertex group B with a weight of 0.1 will be 10 times more influenced by the bone A than by bone B.